# Where Clause Case Statement; ORA-00907: missing parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query and when I run it I get the error message **ORA-00907: missing parenthesis**. When I replace the **CASE** statement with either **x = g and** or **y = g and** it runs as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM
table1,
table2,
table3,
table4,
table5,
table6,
table7,
table8
WHERE
a = b and
c = d and
e = d and
CASE strfldvar
    WHEN 'BROKEN_ARROW' THEN (x = g)
    WHEN 'BROKEN_BOX'   THEN (y = g)
ELSE -1
end 
and
f = h and
i = j
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case` is an expression, not a predicate (i.e condition) : it 'returns' a typed value and can not contain predicate as result (in the `then` parts). In your case (assuming `else -1` means 'no match') :

```
AND g = CASE strfldvar
  WHEN 'BROKEN_ARROW' THEN x
  WHEN 'BROKEN_BOX'   THEN y 
  ELSE NULL -- never match, even if g is null
END
```

although I think it would be simpler to replace it with :

```
AND (
     (strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW' AND x = g) 
  OR (strfldvar = 'BROKEN_BOX' AND y = g)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
CASE strfldvar
    WHEN 'BROKEN_ARROW' THEN (x = g)
    WHEN 'BROKEN_BOX'   THEN (y = g)
ELSE -1
```

have this:

```
x=CASE strfldvar WHEN 'BROKEN_ARROW' THEN g ELSE x END
y=CASE strfldvar WHEN 'BROKEN_ARROW' THEN g ELSE y END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would replace

```
CASE strfldvar
    WHEN 'BROKEN_ARROW' THEN (x = g)
    WHEN 'BROKEN_BOX'   THEN (y = g)
ELSE -1
```

by

```
(CASE WHEN strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW' and x = g then 1 
      WHEN strfldvar = 'BROKEN_BOX' and y = g then 1
      ELSE -1
      END) = 1
```